# Backbone.js - Pass parameters to the model 'url' from initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

Router: entries_router.js.coffee

```
show: (id) ->
  @model = new Raffler.Models.Entry({id: id})
  @model.fetch()
```

model: entry.js.coffee

```
class Raffler.Models.Entry extends Backbone.Model

  initialize: (options) ->
    alert(options.id)

  url: '/api/entries/' + id
```

I'm getting the alert correctly. But how to pass options.id to the URL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model is not part of a collection, specify [Model.urlRoot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) instead of `url`. Backbone will automatically generate an URL in format `[urlRoot]/id`.

```
class Raffler.Models.Entry extends Backbone.Model
    urlRoot: '/api/entries'
```

If your model is a part of a collection, you don't need to set the `url` or `urlRoot`. Specify `collection.url` instead, and Backbone will automatically infer the URL for all models in that collection.